# Как свернуть меню после клика на элемент?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть меню-бургер.

В нём срабатывает collapse (при клике на меню).

Как сделать так, чтобы collapse срабатывал после клика на любой из li-элемнтов из меню?

Нужно, чтобы меню закрывалось после клика.

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
     <?php
         if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() === '/index.php') { ?>
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                 <span class="sr-only">Меню</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
    <?php } else {?>
    <a class="sub-back sub-back-sm" href="/">Назад</a>
    <?php }?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <?php
        if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() === '/index.php') { ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#works">Проекты</a></li>
                <li><a href="#solutions">Решения</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Кто мы</a></li>
            </ul>
    <?php } else {?>
        <a class="sub-back" href="/">Назад</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В теге  надо было поставить это: "data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"